# Android Updating layout from another layout

Tags: android, layout-inflater

well i want to inflate layout and set wanted values from Login Activity to a Drawer Header XML file, goal is to see this values in Main Activity too...

here`s my code:

XML: http://pastebin.com/MDpQh8S8 
CODE: http://pastebin.com/436SNfCN

so what a heck is problem over here?

Comment: Where is object coming from? What is it? By the way, are you getting an error message in logcat?

Comment: Objects coming from fb graph, but setting a simple string does nothing too

Comment: You say this code does nothing? Can you give us the entire method it's currently in please.

Comment: Please post the error you having and the layout

Comment: and about errors: there is no single errors about that, logcat is clean

Comment: post your whole code that will help us in finding what's went wrong.

Comment: This needs more context to understand your problem. Where is this code supposed to be? Is it in `onCreateView()` of a `Fragment`? Are you returning `view` if so?

Comment: this isnot a fragment, it`s an activity
and only this code is related to inflater, so 
email.setText("SOME STRING"); <- Also does not works

Comment: i tried make toast of getting Object and it`s working, it`s displaying my username in toast, so it getting a object

Comment: Probably best to post the entirety of your `Activity` class in that case to get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: and also the XML which you are try to inflate.

Comment: updated code in question

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:
as im including header layout into a MainActivity.xml just finding parameters was enough, didn`t even needed to inflate layout xml

so, pasting whole inflater and changer code to MainAct and then:

```
TextView username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
                                TextView email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
```

just worked fine :) anyway thanks for trying to help me